# Does anyone exist who has used JBoss Errai in their projects?

Tags: gwt, mvp, gwt-mvp, errai

I am searching GWT Design to setup project. I could use [MVP(GWTP)](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/) or [JBoss Errai](http://www.jboss.org/errai). 
I haven't decided yet. Is there anyone who experienced in one of these?

You can give advantages and disadvantages of these frameworks.

Comment: You should also consider the gwt-presenter/gwt-dispatch combo ( http://code.google.com/p/gwt-presenter/, http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dispatch ).

Comment: @Shahzeb I am not satisfied yet....

Comment: @firstthumb did my answer helped?

Answer (score 3):

Errai by far the best for a complete set of tools.
GWT dispatch can be used just by itself if not using Errai or GWTP .

Comment: Correctly Errai sounds good but it is not released completely yet. It is still in development and It doesn't seem to finish at the end of this year.

Answer (score 2):

JBoss Errai is quite "mature" now I think, and I am using it for my commercial projects.

Basically, one of the best features of Errai now (as of this moment) is that it allows really good templating with GWT.

Answer (score 1):

Errai features:

- Errai UI, too easy to learn.
- Errai UI again, the CSS use is native, just in special cases you have to set a CSS style in code.
- LESS Suport.
- JPA on browser.
- CDI through Weld, you can use Seam over spring.
- You can have page navigation (Errai navigation).
- Don't have to declare two interfaces to have interaction with the server.
- Communication with the server in the form of messages, events, or through REST or RPC.

GWT vanilla features:

- UI Binder. What?! more tags to learn? oh come on!
- CSS through Java code.
- Does not have LESS support.
- Does not support CDI injection of services natively.
- Does not support page navigation natively (activities and places works just in one page).
- Does not have any support of client-side persistence.
- You have to declare two interfaces to have interaction with the server (yeah, you can have an assistant that makes the code for you, but is boilerplate code that you have to maintain).
- GWT interaction just by RPC mechanism.

So, IMHO if you can add Errai in your GWT projects your developments will be more comfortable :-)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry could not work about how to add a reply :( any way yes you are right . But Errai bus and for messaging and workspace for UI are  good enough and quite mature and you Iam happily using them in a project with is not due to next 8 months . If however I wanted to go live today Errai would still not be a concern it is quite stable .